# Extend the Attachment Tools Tab with custom button in Outlook Web Add-in

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-web-addins

Is it possible to add custom ribbon button in Attachment Tools Tab , which becomes active only when you select an attachment within a mail?

My objective is to create a functionality where the custom buttons in Attachment tools which can be used to send one or all attachment of the current mail item to a SP site configured.

I am guessing it is part of MessageReadCommandSurface extension point. How do i specify the tab information?

Comment: That feature is currently not part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our user-voice page. (https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins) Please add your request there.

Comment: For now the only way to accomplish your scenario is to add a button to the MessageReadCommandSurface. (or you can be completely in your own tab if you wish). But the button will show on every mail. (you can detect there are no attachments, and display some other functionality / or message to the user)